# Remove whitespace after +44 and quotation marks around lat/long in JSON string with regex

Tags: regex, json

In the example snippet below I have some JSON which needs to be edited (over 1400 entries). I need to achieve 2 things:

1. In this example line: "phone": "+44 2079693900", I need to remove the whitespace between +44 and 2079693900 but for all records. Resulting in: "+442079693900"
2. For latitude and longitude I need to get rid of the double quotes around the numbers, as the API I am using only accepts these values as floats.
   Example: "latitude": "51.51736", needs to be: "latitude": 51.51736

I am most familiar with Ruby, and have done some parsing of JSON with this in the past, but I thought Regex would be the best tool to use for this kind of basic data cleaning task. I have referred to regex101.com and regular-expressions.info but I'm pretty stuck at this point. Thanks in advance!

```
[
  {
    "id": "101756",
    "name": "1 Lombard Street
    "email": "reception@1lombardstreet.com",
    "website": "http://www.1lombardstreet.com",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.5129",
      "longitude": "-0.089",
      "address": {
        "line1": "1 Lombard Street",
        "line2": "",
        "line3": "",
        "postcode": "EC3V 9AA",
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "105371",
    "name": "108 Brasserie",
    "phone": "+44 2079693900",
    "email": "enquiries@108marylebonelane.com",
    "website": "http://www.108brasserie.com",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.51795",
      "longitude": "-0.15079",
      "address": {
        "line1": "108 Marylebone Lane",
        "line2": "",
        "line3": "",
        "postcode": "W1U 2QE",
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "108701",
    "name": "1901 Restaurant",
    "phone": "+44 2076187000",
    "email": "london.restres@andaz.com",
    "website": "http://www.andazdining.com",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.51736",
      "longitude": "-0.08123",
      "address": {
        "line1": "Andaz Hotel",
        "line2": "40 Liverpool Street",
        "line3": "",
        "postcode": "EC2M 7QN",
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "102190",
    "name": "2 Bridge Place",
    "phone": "+44 2078028555",
    "email": "fb@dtlondonvictoria.com",
    "website": "http://crimsonhotels.comdoubletreelondonvictoriadiningpre-theatre-dining",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.49396",
      "longitude": "-0.14343",
      "address": {
        "line1": "2 Bridge Place",
        "line2": "Victoria",
        "line3": "",
        "postcode": "SW1V 1QA",
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "102063",
    "name": "2 Veneti",
    "phone": "+44 2076370789",
    "email": "2veneti@btconnect.com",
    "website": "http://www.2veneti.com",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.5168",
      "longitude": "-0.14673",
      "address": {
        "line1": "10 Wigmore Street",
        "line2": "",
        "line3": "",
        "postcode": "W1U 2RD",
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Are you going to use Ruby for this task?

Comment: I'm trying to do it without Ruby, just using regex exclusively. Is that possible / wise?

Comment: You may try using `("phone":\s*"\+44)\s+|("(?:latitude|longitude)":\s*)"([^"]+)"` and replace with `$1$2$3`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN6tD6/1). Is it working for you?

Comment: Wow, thanks v. much @stribizhev, that worked amazingly well in sublime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
("phone":\s*"\+44)\s+|("(?:latitude|longitude)":\s*)"([^"]+)"
```

With the following replacement:

```
$1$2$3
```

The idea is to capture what we want and not capture what we do not, and then use backreferences to restore the substrings we want to keep.

**Regex explanation**:

The pattern contains 2 alternatives joined with `|` alternation operator:

1. `("phone":\s*"\+44)\s+`:

   - `("phone":\s*"\+44)` - the 1st capturing group matching literal `"phone":` + optional whitespace, then `+44` literally
   - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces that we'll remove
2. `("(?:latitude|longitude)":\s*)"([^"]+)"`:

   - `("(?:latitude|longitude)":\s*)` - the second capturing group matching `"latitude":` or `"longitude":` and 0 or more whitespace characters
   - `"` - Literal `"` that we'll drop
   - `([^"]+)` - the third capturing group matching 1 or more characters other than `"` (we'll keep that)
   - `"` - again, a literal `"` that we'll drop.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN6tD6/1)